# QGIS DB Manager won't connect to PostGIS database, but connection "successful" in browser

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, dbmanager

I have created a spatial database in PGAdmin 4 using PostgreSQL 11. When I connect to the database in QGIS, the connection is successful in browser, but when I go to the DB Manager, it says that I am not connected and I get the error below. I am using the local host Port 5432.

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```py
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 444, in rowCount
    self._refreshIndex(parent, True)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 493, in _refreshIndex
    if item.populate():
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 170, in populate
    if not connection.connect():
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 104, in connect
    return self.connectToUri(uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\plugin.py", line 109, in connectToUri
    self.db = self.databasesFactory(self, uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 68, in databasesFactory
    return PGDatabase(connection, uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 112, in __init__
    Database.__init__(self, connection, uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\plugin.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.connector = self.connectorsFactory(uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\plugin.py", line 115, in connectorsFactory
    return PostGisDBConnector(uri)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\connector.py", line 108, in __init__
    self._checkGeometryColumnsTable()
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\postgis\connector.py", line 168, in _checkGeometryColumnsTable
    self.has_geometry_columns_access = priv[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.4.2-Madeira Madeira, 22034aa070

Comment: Are you sure, you installed postgis correctly? It seems to be not the Case, because _checkGeometryColumnsTable fails.

Comment: Yes, make sure you installed postgis and `CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS;` in your DB